# In React Native, is there a way to change the color of the button based on a boolean from a database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, background-color

So, I'm a **literal newbie** to React-Native and I just started experimenting out stuff. So, I ran across this issue of having the color of button either "green" or "red" based on the boolean value present on a database.

So, at this point, I'm using Google's "Firebase" as my primary database.
This is the base code which I'm trying to work out.

```js
import {StatusBar} from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Pressable, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app';
import {getDatabase, ref, onValue, set} from 'firebase/database';
import {color} from 'react-native-reanimated';

const firebaseConfig = {};
initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      l1: this.readVals('l1/'),
    };
  }

  readVals(path) {
    const db = getDatabase();
    const reference = ref(db, path);
    onValue(reference, (snapshot) => {
      const value = snapshot.val().obj;
      return value;
    });
  
  }

  setVals(path) {
      const db = getDatabase();
      const reference = ref(db, path);
      const val = this.state.l1;
      set(reference, {
        obj: !val
      });
      this.state.l1 = !val;
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Pressable
          style={({pressed}) => [
            {
              backgroundColor: this.state.l1 ? '#FF0000' : '#00FF00',
            },
            styles.button,
          ]} onPress={() => {this.setVals('l1/')}}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Button</Text>
        </Pressable>

        <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#FF0000',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  getButton: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 7,
    marginTop: 20,
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#00FF00',
  },

  button: {
    flex: 0.15,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.25)',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginTop: 20,
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
    // backgroundColor: '#E84C3D'
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
});
```

When I press the button, the color changes as expected. But is there a way to change the color based on the value present in the database?

For example, in this case, I want the button to have the color 'green' from the moment the app is loaded up, if the value at location 'l1/'(in my example) in "firebase" has the value set to `true`, and similarly, I want the color to stay 'red' if the value at 'l1/' is `false`.

Can this be implemented?
If yes, any help received is very helpful to me.
Thank you.

P.S. Also, please note the fact that I'm very new to the field of React-Native(Sorry).

Answer (score 1):

for `reRender` screen you have to use `state` and when it's changed your Screen `render` again . and seems you used that . but you can try another way like that . at fist call to get your data in  `componentDidMount` like this:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMount");
     this.setState({  l1: this.readVals('l1/') });
  }
```

if l1 changed , it's should to be work for you .

other hand if you want `UI` change immediately after changing database , you can try 2 way . at first you use `socket programming` like `signalR` component . for more info [this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-signalr)

second way in `firebase` you can use `firebaseMessaging` and in this way when database changed ,json data send via `notification` . for more info [see this](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage)

Comment: Thanks for your response. But unfortunately, this does no good. I want the background color to be set by default to either of green or red depending on the boolean from the database.

Comment: Also, when I change the value in my database, it does not change the background color.

Comment: in my solution when database change , when ever user open the screen color will change . but if you want it change immediately when database is change , you have to try another way . i edit my answer and explain that .

Comment: @MeisaamSaba I'm sorry but when I tried to implement your code, it did not change the color of the background of the button on loading the page. Maybe you might be missing some part of the code that seems different from yours?

Comment: first check on loading screen your 'complonentDidmont' is call or not with console log . then check value of state after set like this:  this.setState({ 
  l1: this.readVals('l1/')
  }, 
  () => console.log(this.state.l1),
)

Comment: Oh no. I think you have misunderstood my problem. Yes, it does output for "componentDidMount" on starting the program, but the background of my button, as for my requirement, does not change.

Comment: @Just_ish1122 as I edited answer . for changing immediately , you have to use firebase messaging in your app , this solution receive data in background with notification as you sent it in backend

Comment: ah, how do I implement that over here?

Answer (score 0):

As you are working on class base component you can call an firebase function in a **componentWillMount** and get the color and save it to your state.

**componentWillMount** run before rendering so once you get the data you can setState and then by that state you can change the color of the button.

**TRY THIS**

```
import {StatusBar} from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Pressable, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app';
import {getDatabase, ref, onValue, set} from 'firebase/database';
import {color} from 'react-native-reanimated';

const firebaseConfig = {};
initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      l1: this.readVals('l1/'),
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const value = this.readVals('l1/');
    this.setState({l1: value});
  }

  readVals(path) {
    const db = getDatabase();
    const reference = ref(db, path);
    onValue(reference, (snapshot) => {
      const value = snapshot.val().obj;
      return value;
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Pressable
          style={({pressed}) => [
            {
              backgroundColor: this.state.l1 ? '#FF0000' : '#00FF00',
            },
            styles.button,
          ]}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Button</Text>
        </Pressable>

        <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#FF0000',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  getButton: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 7,
    marginTop: 20,
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#00FF00',
  },

  button: {
    flex: 0.15,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.25)',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginTop: 20,
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
    // backgroundColor: '#E84C3D'
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
});
```

Comment: Just one quick question, does this mean that when I change the value in my database, it changes the color of the button?

Comment: Firebase is realtime so I think yes it will show the changes.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think it is changing over here.

Comment: for the first time are you getting the right color that you set in your database?

Comment: I think you should look over to the line ```<Pressable style={({ pressed }) => [{         backgroundColor: this.state.l1 ?  '#FF0000' : '#00FF00' }, styles.button ]} ```
Over here, the color was supposed to change when I press.

Comment: are you getting the value from firebase first check that try to log it

Comment: I have edited the code in such a way that when I press the button, the color swaps to either of green or red after pressing. But the color is by default at 'green' when loading. Any idea on how I could have the color of the button either green or red depending on value that was stored in the database?